# Will strategy.exit() "restart" after strategy.cancel() if criteria met again?

Tags: pine-script

Okay here's the deal. I have been trying to get my strategy.exit() to work for a while now but with an "if statement" of session.ismarket.

The problem is that I believe that once the "if statement" is met, than it triggers the strategy.exit() to wait on the stop, limit, trail_stop etc to trigger.

My exits were generally working but some were randomly closing at 3:00 a.m. which I can't trade so that is a problem.

Here is my solution that I *think* works, but I wanted to verify on here with all the smart people.

```
if strategy.position_size>0 and session.ismarket
    strategy.exit('TP Long', qty_percent=50, limit=LongTakeProfit, comment='TP-L')
else if session.ismarket!=true
    strategy.cancel('TP Long')
```

My questions it: Will the strategy.exit() "restart" after the market opens again on the following day, then cancel when the market closes, then "restart" when the market opens again, etc etc. as long as the target has not been met?

I am pretty positive that this works but I don't know if it failed on any of the 600+ trades I am backtesting. I also, can't find detailed info on the strategy.cancel() command online anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strategy.cancel()
```

> It is a command to cancel/deactivate pending orders by referencing
> their names, which were generated by the functions: strategy.order,
> strategy.entry and strategy.exit.

So, yeah, it will cancel your pending exit order when it is out of the session and you will be placing a new exit order when `strategy.position_size>0 and session.ismarket` is `true`.

Comment: Thank you! I just found the “execution model” and it makes much more sense how it works now.